# Context locals - how do they make local context variables global?

Tags: python

I was reading through the Flask doc - and came across [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#id4):

> ... For web applications it’s crucial to
>   react to the data a client sent to the
>   server. In Flask this information is
>   provided by the global request object.
>   If you have some experience with
>   Python you might be wondering how that
>   object can be global and how Flask
>   manages to still be threadsafe. The
>   answer are context locals ...

Now I understood context locals to be stuff like the `with` statement (certainly thats what the [python 2.6 doc](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html) seems to suggest). Im struggling to see how this would allow you to have globally accessible vars that reside in a local namespace? How does this conceptually work?

Also: globals are generally considered filthy I take it, so why is this OK ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are actually proxy objects to the real objects so that when you reference one you get access to the object for your current thread.

An example would be the `request` object. You can see this being set up in [globlals.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/globals.py) and then imported into the [__init__.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/__init__.py) for flask.

The benefit of this is that you can access the request just by doing

```
from flask import request
```

and write methods like

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"
```

without having to pass the request around as a parameter.

This is making use of some of the reusable code libraries from [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org).

Comment: Sorry if i'm being dense: but if i get this correctly they push the context onto a sort of 'stackframe' and then are able to appropriately route the attribute call to the correct linked object based on this stack?

Comment: If you grab a copy of the [source for Werkzeug](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/W/Werkzeug/Werkzeug-0.6.2.tar.gz) and look in `local.py` you will see that the `Local` class basically uses a dictionary with the current thread ID as the key to store and retrieve the right objects transparently. This is the the limit of what I can deduce without setting up some tests to figure out what the code is doing.

Comment: I don't think a stack is necessary for the above. This is just a guess but the stack may just add an extra layer related to this comment in the documentation you linked to: *It does that in an intelligent way that one application can invoke another application without breaking.*